# Collection element of type 'void *' is not an Objective-C objectというエラーが解決できません。（旧タイトル；Expected ';' at end of declaration list というエラーが解決できません。）

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

※以前掲載した「Expected ';' at end of declaration list というエラーが解決できません。」という質問にご返答をいただき、修正後に新たなエラーが発生したため質問内容を編集いたしました※

Objective-Cで、Collection element of type 'void *' is not an Objective-C objectエラーが解決できません。

該当箇所は「NSArray* _lines = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", nil]」です。
原因がお分かりになる方ご教授いただけると幸いです。

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface ThirdViewController ()

@end

const int ChangeCheckCell = 1;
NSMutableArray* checkboxArray;
NSArray* _lines = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];

@implementation ThirdViewController {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

Comment: エラーメッセージにあるとおり、該当箇所の末尾にセミコロン`;`を追加すれば良いのでは？ 試してみても変わらないとか何か別のエラーになるとかならその状況を追記してみてください。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。該当箇所の末尾に「；」を追加ても同じエラーが表示されました。

Comment: 質問内容を編集して置き換えてしまうと、付いた回答が合わなくなってしまうのでそういうことはしないでください。最初の内容は残して新しい状況は追記とするか、あるいは新規に質問を起こしてください。その上で新しい状況は、`@implementation ... {`がその後の`}`で閉じたさらに後に`- (void)viewDidLoad {`があるからでは？ `}`の前に移動してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

根本の問題は

```
NSArray* _lines = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];
```

の最後のセミコロンがない事です。ただし、変数を宣言、初期化している場所もよろしくないので、多分、書きたいコードは以下のようになるでしょう。

```
#import "ThirdViewController.h"

@interface ThirdViewController ()

@end

const int ChangeCheckCell = 1;
NSMutableArray* checkboxArray;
NSArray* _lines = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", nil];　　　　　　

@implementation ThirdViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
```

`@implementation`から`@end`までの間に、関数の内部で無い変数宣言は出来ません。
`ThirdViewController`クラスのメンバーでない`ThirdViewController.m`の中でだけ見える変数を宣言したいのであれば、`@implementation`の外に書くべきです。

また、もし、`checkboxArray`と `_lines`がクラスのメンバーである場合は、変数宣言は、`ThirdViewController.h`の`@interface`から`@end`の間に宣言を書き、変数の初期化を`viewDidLoad`の中で行うと良いでしょう。

修正後の質問については

`@implementation ThirdViewController`の後ろの`{}`が余計だからです。

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。修正後に新たなエラーが発生したため、掲載内容を修正いたしました。

Comment: 回答を追記しました